# Exclude files from Gulp stream if contents contain a string

Tags: laravel, gulp

I have a gulp task that looks like this:

```js
    return src(['storage/framework/views/*.php'])
        .pipe(htmlmin({
            collapseWhitespace: true,
        }))
        .pipe(dest('storage/framework/views'));
```

It takes the compiled views from Laravel and pipes them through htmlmin.

This works fine for the HTML views, but it corrupts the content of the Markdown views.

Unfortunately I can't add an exclusion in `src([...])` because the file names are all hashes. I need to be able to inspect the content of the file and exclude the file if the file contains `mail::message`.

Trying to solve this myself, there's [gulp-contains](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-contains), but that only seems to be able to throw an error if the file contains the given string. I can't figure out a way to use its callback to exclude the file.

There's also [gulp-ignore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ignore), but that doesn't seem to be able to exclude individual files out of the stream.

Assuming there are three template files, where `y.php` is a Markdown template. The ideal solution would be something like:

```js
    return src(['storage/framework/views/*.php']) // [x.php, y.php, z.php]
        .pipe(exclude_files_containing('mail::message')) // [x.php, z.php]
        .pipe(htmlmin({
            collapseWhitespace: true,
        }))
        .pipe(dest('storage/framework/views'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gulp-filter`

```
const filter = require('gulp-filter');

gulp.task("TaskExample", function () {

  // return true if want the file in the stream
  // return file to exclude the file

  const excludeMessageFilter = filter(function (file) {

    let contents = file.contents.toString();
    return !contents.match('mail::message');
  });

  return gulp.src('storage/framework/views/*.php')

    .pipe(excludeMessageFilter)

    // .pipe(htmlmin(...
    // .pipe(gulp.dest('''''''));
});
```